# button click effect without having another picture in Android

Tags: java, android, button

I have my button in my app as a regular Buttons but with customized background (see this to know what I mean http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=56). 
Everything works fine. However,  I want to indicate to the user that he is pressing the button WITHOUT having another "pressed" version on the button (I am aware of how to give the button another image upon pressing)

I currently use onTouchListner and apply colorFilters on the Button upon pressing and clearing on releasing but detecting the press and release * accurately* in touch mode didn't work fine with me

**EDIT**

Here is how I want it.

not pressed: 
[not pressed](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-pPbirVV1zsg/UD3jK9e4gSI/AAAAAAAAAGI/yYVD2kf1bcs/s512/Screenshot_2012-08-29-12-36-38.png)

pressed (same exact image file):
[pressed](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-oqIDDJkfMdY/UD3iyYkP6jI/AAAAAAAAAGA/c7neX5P3IyU/s512/Screenshot_2012-08-29-12-36-44.png)

I had the highlight effect using colorFilter
                 `getBtn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF838B83, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`

Comment: I am not sure how to use selector to achieve that keeping in mind I wanna use only one file for the image

Comment: a selector is just one xml file. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

you could just create a Selector for your Button, so you can set it as its background but still have a click-effect whenever you click it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="insert color"
                android:endColor="insert color"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="insert color" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item android:state_pressed="false" >        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="insert color"
                android:startColor="insert color"
               />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="insert color" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

set this xml file as your background for your button:

```
mybtn.setbackground(R.drawable.thexmlfileabove);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it but didn't solve the issue because my buttons have transparent background. So a solution to that would be highlighting the exact size of the button itself without adding margins. 
Here is what the sample button looks like using your code:
![image](http://i49.tinypic.com/mlr3pw.png)

Comment: So you want diferent images to appear when you click on the button? the red cross image and one in pressed state?

Comment: No, I want to keep the same image but highlight it to indicate it is pressed. 
for example, here is the button not pressed: 
[not pressed](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-pPbirVV1zsg/UD3jK9e4gSI/AAAAAAAAAGI/yYVD2kf1bcs/s512/Screenshot_2012-08-29-12-36-38.png)
and here is the pressed: 
[pressed](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-oqIDDJkfMdY/UD3iyYkP6jI/AAAAAAAAAGA/c7neX5P3IyU/s512/Screenshot_2012-08-29-12-36-44.png)
Here what I did is applied colorFliter to the image:

    `getBtn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF838B83, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`

Comment: @AlAsiri have you found a way to handle this situation? I am currently looking for the same thing to use just one image.